# Isn't there any way to execute a post function script for free?

Tags: jira

I'd like to perform operations like automatically update a field based on another field's value (for example if the assignee field is empty automatically assign to a default, set an hidden "due date" field based on the release-fix start date, ecc.) or write a custom validator that does validations based on a combination of values.

Every time I go searching on the jira forum I find java fragments of code, so everything seems to be possible, but it seems it is only at one condition: to buy the [script runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) plugin!

It seems strange to me: of course this plugin seems to be doing a lot of boilerplate for you but...what if I want to make a little more effort but still not payng for something that, in my opinion, should be free? I'm already paying the software license...isn't there another way to perform such post actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try MyGroovy. It provides similar features. For tasks like execution post-functions I suppose it would fits good.

Comment: Seems great! Problem is that, after installing it, it crashes caused by  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.jira.jql.query.IssueIdJoinQueryFactory

Comment: Honestly don't know, maybe update UPM to latest version would help. Usually it installs without any exceptions. And check that you pick properly plugin version which supports your Jira version.

Comment: Great! It was just the jira version. Is there any tutorial I can start with?

Comment: Sure, you can start here https://github.com/mailru/jira-scripts and a bit of plugin interface here https://github.com/atlascommunity/jira-plugins-groovy/wiki